# How to get MailItem content on loading a mail in Outlook

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, mime, smime, mailitem

I am creating an Addin for outlook and I have a requirement to fetch the mail content and parse it by my code. Problem I am facing with is to get the mail content. 
Using Property accessor("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E"), I managed to get the mail header but not the mail content.
Kindly note that, I don't want the mailITem.Body that returns me the html or plain text content. Instead, what I need is the complete mail content.

Thanks,
Adi.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook does not store or use complete MIME source. It does not even convert messages to MIME until you send them through SMTP. And even for received messages, an incoming message does not have to be in the MIME format if, for example, it is coming from another Exchange mailbox in the same domain.

Comment: ok, thanks for your response. Even if it is not in MIME format, is there a way to get the mail content please? Reason I am asking is, I want to fetch the encrypted mail and decrypt it.
Kindly note that, I don't want the mailItem.Body or mail.HTMLBody.

Comment: If it is not MIME, there is no format that Outlook understand with the whole message content. What encrypted content do you mean? For encrypted/signed messages, the original (p7m) data is still there.

Comment: I don't need p7m file. It will have just the signature of a sender if the message is signed. Instead, what I need is the actual encrypted message. I need to use my own decryption logic there.

Comment: Does Outlook actually treat it as an encrypted message?

Comment: If I have the respective certificate with private key in MS certificate store, it does decrypt and display. If the certificate is not present in MS Cert store, Outlook wont decrypt. I need the plain message content when outlook is not able to decrypt message.